# AJAX: is the new loaded content using the same css file?

Tags: css, ajax

When I load content with AJAX, is this content supposed to automatically use the preloaded main page css style ?

For example, if I load a `<span class="smallText">hello</span>` with AJAX.

Is this new HTML using the `default.css` file with

```
.smallText {
   font-size:6px;
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I load content with AJAX, is this content supposed to automatically use the preloaded main page css style ?

Yes. The HTML is injected into the context of the current page, and subject to all its CSS rules.

Comment: @Patrick it's because the Ajax content is outside `div#page` which defines a `font-size:10px;` do you use Firebug? If not, make sure you install it, it's a lifesaver for such things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will use the CSS of the page it's loaded in.